# Javascript Range Filter To Dom (user uploaded image)

Tags: javascript, dom, range

The goal of my code is to allow users to upload their own image and be able to blur it. The image uploading part works, but the range value isn't.

Example: A user uploads an image and they want to blur it 20%, they can move the slider to about 20% and it would change the image blur with the id "userIMG".

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.slidecontainer {
    width: 100%;
}

.slider {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 25px;
    background: #d3d3d3;
    outline: none;
    opacity: 0.7;
    -webkit-transition: .2s;
    transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background: black;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background: #4CAF50;
    cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<input type="file" onchange="previewFile()"><br>
<img id="userIMG" src="" height="200" alt="Image preview...">
<script>
   function previewFile(){
       var preview = document.querySelector('img'); //selects the query named img
       var file    = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0]; //sames as here
       var reader  = new FileReader();

       reader.onloadend = function () {
           preview.src = reader.result;
       }

       if (file) {
           reader.readAsDataURL(file); //reads the data as a URL
       } else {
           preview.src = "";
       }
  }

  previewFile();  //calls the function named previewFile()
  </script>

<div class="slidecontainer">
  <p>Blur Range Slider</p>
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="efBlur-RANGE">
</div>
<script>
function effectBlur() {
    // Standard syntax
    var x = document.getElementById("efBlur-RANGE").value;
    document.getElementById("userIMG").style.blur = "blur(x%)";

    // Safari 6.0 - 9.0
    var x = document.getElementById("efBlur-RANGE").value;
    document.getElementById("userIMG").style.WebkitBlur = "blur(x%)";  
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't see you ever call `effectBlur`?  ... Did you forget to attach a handler to your slider?

Comment: @LGSon I did, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the event listener to you input. This will trigger your function every time you **change** the input.

Also, use `filter: blur(x px);` for the css blur

I think it might cause troubles with IE, checked on [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=filter)

```js
function effectBlur() {
    // Standard syntax
    var x = document.getElementById("efBlur-RANGE").value;
    document.getElementById("userIMG").style.filter = "blur("+x+"px)";

    // Safari 6.0 - 9.0
    var x = document.getElementById("efBlur-RANGE").value;
    document.getElementById("userIMG").style.WebkitBlur = "blur(x%)";  
}

document.getElementById('efBlur-RANGE').addEventListener('change', effectBlur)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.slidecontainer {
    width: 100%;
}

.slider {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 25px;
    background: #d3d3d3;
    outline: none;
    opacity: 0.7;
    -webkit-transition: .2s;
    transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background: black;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background: #4CAF50;
    cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<input type="file" onchange="previewFile()"><br>
<img id="userIMG" src="" height="200" alt="Image preview...">
<script>
   function previewFile(){
       var preview = document.querySelector('img'); //selects the query named img
       var file    = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0]; //sames as here
       var reader  = new FileReader();

       reader.onloadend = function () {
           preview.src = reader.result;
       }

       if (file) {
           reader.readAsDataURL(file); //reads the data as a URL
       } else {
           preview.src = "";
       }
  }

  previewFile();  //calls the function named previewFile()
  </script>

<div class="slidecontainer">
  <p>Blur Range Slider</p>
  <input type="range" min="0" max="10" value="5" class="slider" id="efBlur-RANGE">
</div>
<script>

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code got many problems: the Webkit property doesn't exist, percentage is invalid in blur filter, x isn't a variable,... Fixed code for you

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.slidecontainer {
    width: 100%;
}

.slider {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 25px;
    background: #d3d3d3;
    outline: none;
    opacity: 0.7;
    -webkit-transition: .2s;
    transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background: black;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background: #4CAF50;
    cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<input type="file" onchange="previewFile()"><br>
<img id="userIMG" src="" height="200" alt="Image preview...">
<script>
   function previewFile(){
       var preview = document.querySelector('img'); //selects the query named img
       var file    = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0]; //sames as here
       var reader  = new FileReader();

       reader.onloadend = function () {
           preview.src = reader.result;
       }

       if (file) {
           reader.readAsDataURL(file); //reads the data as a URL
       } else {
           preview.src = "";
       }
  }

  previewFile();  //calls the function named previewFile()
  </script>

<div class="slidecontainer">
  <p>Blur Range Slider</p>
  <input type="range" min="0" max="30" value="2" class="slider" id="efBlur-RANGE">
</div>
<script>
    // Standard syntax
  var efBlur = document.getElementById("efBlur-RANGE")
  efBlur.onchange = function(evt) {
    var x = evt.target.value;
    document.getElementById("userIMG").style.filter = "blur("+x+"px)";

    // Safari 6.0 - 9.0
  document.getElementById("userIMG").setAttribute("style","-webkit-filter:blur(" + x + "px)")

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```